# Syncing between computers / batch download

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

I have synced files from two different devices. Now I want to copy to contents of the synced files to the other device. Using the web interface, it seems only possible to download one file at a time. Is there a way to setup automatic sync or to download all the files in a folder with one step? Thanks in advance for your time.

I was using the web interface to ubuntu, but an answer for Ubuntu One would also be ok.

Edit: I was trying to copy the files automatically between devices. I found a checkbox on Ubuntu One that says sync locally that seems to work.

But from the web interface is it possible to do a download of multiple files in a folder at  one time?

Comment: To be clear what is the "web interface to Ubuntu?" What kind of devices are you syncing?

Comment: If the files are already synced, why do you want to copy it again?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want can be done. There is no batch download web interface in the Ubuntu One site. However, you can sync multiple (more than two) computers using the Ubuntu One client application in each computer.

Once the new device (computer) is set up, the Ubuntu One client application will download all the files from the web and keep all the computers in sync.

I hope this is helpful.